# How to show multiple images preview with additional button in rails form & dragonfly

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

What is the best way to show preview for each of three different images with an additional button?

My form:

```
<%= @discount.errors.full_messages.first if @discount.errors.any? %>
<%= form_for @discount, url: {action: "create"} do |f| %>
    <%= f.label :name, "Name" %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :name, placeholder: "Name" %><br />
    <%= f.label :description, "Description" %><br />
    <%= f.text_area :description, placeholder: "Description" %><br />
    <%= f.label :start_date, "Valid from:" %><br />
    <%= f.date_select(:start_date) %><br />
    <%= f.label :expiration_date, "Valid to:" %><br />
    <%= f.date_select(:expiration_date) %><br />

    <%= f.label :thumbnail, "Thumbnail" %><br />
    <%= f.file_field :thumbnail, :html => {:multipart => true}  %><br />
    <div id="file1">
        <%= f.submit "Crop1" %><br />
    </div>
    <%= f.label :image, "Image" %><br />
    <%= f.file_field :image, :html => {:multipart => true}  %><br />
    <div id="file2">
        <%= f.submit "Crop2" %><br />
    </div>
    <%= f.label :activate_image, "Activate image" %><br />
    <%= f.file_field :activate_image, :html => {:multipart => true}  %><br />
    <div id="file3">
        <%= f.submit "Crop3" %><br />
    </div>


    <%= f.submit "Save" %>
<% end %>
```

I would like to have image preview in each div and show div only if image is uploaded. For file upload I used dragonfly gem.

For image preview I have tried something like this, but it will work only for one image upload:

```
<div id="file1">
  <%= f.submit "Crop1" %><br />
  <input type='file' onchange="readURL(this);" />
  <img id="img_prev" src="#" alt="your image" />
  <script>
      function readURL(input) {
          if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
              var reader = new FileReader();

              reader.onload = function (e) {
                  $('#img_prev')
                          .attr('src', e.target.result)
                          .width(150)
                          .height(200);
              };

              reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
          }
      }
  </script>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Re-use the same code for all divs and mark three different places to show the image in. The following should work.

```
<script>
  function readURL(input) {
      if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
          var reader = new FileReader();

          reader.onload = function (e) {
              $(input).parent().find('.img_prev') //finds the parent div and gets the img_prev contained inside
                      .attr('src', e.target.result)
                      .width(150)
                      .height(200);
          };

      reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
  }
</script>
<div id="file1">
  <%= f.submit "Crop1" %><br />
  <input type='file' onchange="readURL(this);" />
  <img class="img_prev" src="#" alt="your image" />
</div>
<div id="file2">
  <%= f.submit "Crop1" %><br />
  <input type='file' onchange="readURL(this);" />
  <img class="img_prev" src="#" alt="your image" />
</div>
<div id="file3">
  <%= f.submit "Crop1" %><br />
  <input type='file' onchange="readURL(this);" />
  <img class="img_prev" src="#" alt="your image" />
</div>
```

Comment: I have modified html input to rails input and it seems to work fine with preview, but what about showing Crop button only if file is selected?

Comment: It depends on what you're trying to achieve. I don't know the scope, but showing a button on click is as simple as 

`$('.your-div').on('click', function() { $('.crop-button').show() })`